# underlining a superscript, WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, underline

Is there a way to underline a superscript in [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms), but **not** as it is done by default, but as it is described [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Rzm.png)? It should be done in [richtextbox](/questions/tagged/richtextbox).

**My simple code:**
Let's say, we have simple RTB called fixedRichTextBoxcs1 and we have a button1:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.fixedRichTextBoxcs1.Text = "This is result";
        this.fixedRichTextBoxcs1.Select(0, this.fixedRichTextBoxcs1.Text.Length);
        this.fixedRichTextBoxcs1.SelectionFont = new Font(this.fixedRichTextBoxcs1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline);
        this.fixedRichTextBoxcs1.Select(0, 1);
        this.fixedRichTextBoxcs1.SelectionCharOffset = 15;
    }
```

And it doesn't work as intended, the result is:
[image]

Comment: The answer to your question is `Yes`. You basically answered it yourself.

Comment: Can you expand your comment? The topic I've given a link to concerns WPF and unfortunately I am not familiar with it yet.

Comment: @PawełPoręba as Kevin said, it is possible and I posted an example for you in windows forms

Comment: @RezaAghaei I commented under your answer, it doesn't solve my problem, it's default behaviour.

Comment: It works just fine.  "Pretty" is not a word that applies, this isn't supported directly by the text rendering engine.  RTB tries its best to do what you ask.  If you want 1 to be underlined more visibly then you'll have to ask for that, set the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties so only the "1" is selected.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you provide some example? I've really tried that, selecting only "1" and it doesn't work. Why is it that the code proposed by RezaAghaei works for him, but not for me? We have the same OS version, .NET version and VS too..

Comment: Your screenshots are useless, post code.

Comment: @HansPassant I've added some code to my question.

Comment: Hmm, your snippet has nothing to do with your screenshot.  And is buggy, using both this.fixedRichTextBoxcs1 and this.richTextBox.  This just can't seem to get better, maybe you ought to try it again a year from now.

Comment: @HansPassant I've corrected it, sorry. Can u check this now? FixedRichTextBox is the one that remove AutoWordSelection bug and also implement "RichEdit50W" instead of "RichEdit20W". But this code also doesn't work for default RTB. Is it still something I do wrong?

Comment: No, the answer doesn't solve my problem, it just doesn't work.